# How to Achieve -r,-b,-f in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Can't implement -f(formfeed),-b(backspace),-r(replace). While uploading i need to show progress using above commands.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d \r", i);
    }
}
```

In Eclipse in the *Console* view, this creates 100 lines one below the other, whereas on the command line the same line will be updated.

Comment: Unclear. Are you asking how to overwrite the content of the previously printed line in Java?

Comment: yes .------------------ into #----------, #####----,########. i need to update progress like this in console output

Comment: it working fine in  one of the online compiler

Comment: What is working fine in which online compiler? Show your code.

Comment: Interesting: Using e.g. `System.out.printf("%3d \r", i);` in a loop works fine when run with plain `javac` and `java`, but prints on different lines when run in Eclipse.

Comment: The Eclipse console does not support overwriting previous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse console does not support any of \b, \f, or \r properly. \r is treated as a new line, the others as spaces.

This is described in Eclipse bug [76936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936) which has been open since 2004 and despite some attempts to fix is still open.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.